# Squid service has been running for days without any auth

Tags: security, squid

Today I found plenty of malicious requests in Squid access log:

`http://119.161.9.14/config/pwtoken_get?`

I think it's safe for me and other users as websites use cookies to track visitors, so the "hacker" won't get anything, right?

Comment: 1. Why does your Squid server accept connections from the Internet? 2. Why isn't your firewall blocking that port from the Internet? 3. Why don't you have any authentications whatsoever?!

Comment: It was used as a HTTP proxy for somebody outside my Local Network so it accepts Internet connections. But you are right, I just added authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this person is trying to do is get the log-in for Yahoo. More info: [here](http://carbonize.co.uk/ymsg16.html). I don't think he will be able to get anything of your server because Squid doesn't store cookies by default.